# after mkdir, files are not being generated within the created folder

Tags: tcl

After **mkdir**, files are not being generated within the created folder

```
set curdir [file dir [info script]];
puts "path $curdir "
catch {cd $curdir}

set odir [file mkdir $curdir/OPFiles];

set OPDir [file dirname [ puts "$odir"]]
puts "path-- $OutPutDir"


set Summary [file join "$OPDir" Sum.txt];
puts "path-- $Summary"

set ECount [file join "$OutPutDir" EC.txt]
puts "path-- $ECount"
```

Comment: Why do you believe that `file join` is the appropriate function to create files?

Comment: set curdir [file dir [info script]];
 puts "path-- $curdir "
 catch {cd $curdir}
set OutPutDircr [file mkdir $curdir/OutPutFiles];
set OutPutDir "$curdir/OutPutFiles"
set Summary [file join "$OutPutDir" Summary.txt]
set ECount [file join "$OutPutDir" Ecount.txt]

Comment: so that i can call that particular file, open it and write results and then close it

Comment: but the file doesn't exist yet. You just created the folder. To create the file, you need to use `open filepath w` (and close it afterwards when you are done).

Answer (score 2):

The `file mkdir` command makes directories, not files. The `file join` makes file pathnames, but doesn't actually make the file. To make a file, you need to `open` it for writing (and eventually `close` it again).

```
set curdir [file dirname [info script]]
set odir [file join $curdir OPFiles]

file mkdir $odir

set Summary [file join $odir Sum.txt]

set handle [open $Summary "w"]
puts $handle "this would be some summary text..."
close $handle
```

Also, the results of `file mkdir` and `puts` are always an empty string (when there isn't an error). You probably don't want to use them. And in my experience, `cd` is usually best avoided in scripts, *especially* if you want them to be at all reusable, as it changes the absolute meaning of *all* relative filenames.

Comment: Thanks Donal. will try to use it.